# Why won't numpy calculate std deviation on one 5-element list and not another?

Tags: python, numpy, sympy

I'm trying to use Python to do some simple statics problems and generate a graph of the results. For some reason, NumPy doesn't accept my data when trying to calculate the standard deviation of my calculated results (but succeeds with the raw data lists). I need to change `yerr=[std(f10)...` on line 61 to `yerr=[std(solf10)...` . Every time I try, however, the python environment throws the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\evanlane\Dropbox\School\f13\homework\statics\lab1\data.py", line 70, in <module>
    ax.errorbar(x, [solf10avg,solf12avg,solf15avg], yerr=[std(solf10),std(f12),std(f15)], lw=1.5)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python33\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py", line 2590, in std
    keepdims=keepdims)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python33\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_methods.py", line 107, in _std
    ret = um.sqrt(ret)
AttributeError: 'Float' object has no attribute 'sqrt'
```

I tried to find out if the data is structured differently with `print(type(f10), type(solf10))` but that shows them both to be `<class 'list'>` types. How should I massage the data to fit better?
I'm new to python, so if you have any additional style corrections, please let me know as well.

Full code:

```
# Imports
from sympy import *
from numpy import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Constants
g = 9.81

# Given data
l1, l2, l3 = 0.023, 0.07492, 0.0325
mw = 0.220
w = g*mw

# Collected data
m10 = [1540,1500,1400,1400,1670]
m10kg = [x/1000 for x in m10]

m12 = [1220, 1300, 1200, 1050, 900]
m12kg = [x/1000 for x in m12]

m15 = [770, 790, 740, 760, 750]
m15kg = [x/1000 for x in m15]

# Conversion from mass to force in Newtons due to gravity
f10, f12, f15 = [x*g for x in m10kg], [y*g for y in m12kg], [z*g for z in m15kg]

# Averages of the data
f10avg, f12avg, f15avg = mean(f10), mean(f12), mean(f15)

# Instantiate symbolic variables
fr, my = symbols('fr, my')

# Equation of moment about the origin
sumMoments = Eq(fr, (w*l2+my*(l1+l2))/(l1+l2+l3))

# Newtons acting axially on the straw, solved from equation
solf10 = [solve(sumMoments.subs(my,x)) for x in f10]
solf12 = [solve(sumMoments.subs(my,x)) for x in f12]
solf15 = [solve(sumMoments.subs(my,x)) for x in f15]

solf10 = [x for sub1 in solf10 for x in sub1]
solf12 = [x for sub1 in solf12 for x in sub1]
solf15 = [x for sub1 in solf15 for x in sub1]

solf10avg, solf12avg, solf15avg = mean(solf10), mean(solf12), mean(solf15)

# Plotting section
# ------------------

# X positions
x = [10,12,15]

#Uncomment for hand-drawn style
#plt.xkcd()

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

offset = .5

ax.errorbar(x, [solf10avg,solf12avg,solf15avg], yerr=[std(f10),std(f12),std(f15)], lw=1.5)
plt.text(x[0],solf10avg + offset, r'  $F_{10 cm}=\ %.3f \ N$' %(solf10avg), fontsize=18)
plt.text(x[2],solf15avg + offset, r'  $F_{15 cm}=\ %.3f \ N$' %(solf15avg), fontsize=18)
plt.text(x[1],solf12avg + offset, r'  $F_{12 cm}=\ %.3f \ N$' %(solf12avg), fontsize=18)

plt.xlim([9,20])
plt.ylim([0,20])

plt.title("Straw Yield Point Test", fontsize=24)
plt.xlabel("Length (cm)", fontsize=18)
plt.ylabel("Axial Force on Straw\n at Yield (N)", fontsize=18)

plt.minorticks_on()
plt.grid(which="both")

#plt.savefig('fig_1.pdf')

plt.show()
```

Comment: Can you strip this down to remove all the irrelevant stuff and make it easier for someone to debug it? See [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) for guidelines.

Comment: Is there a reason you are using `list`s instead of numpy `array`s?  Also, are the length of `f10` and `solf10` different?

Comment: Doing `import *` is a bad idea, but doing it from both `sympy` and `numpy` is a really bad idea, because they both define some of the same names.

Comment: @abarnert Thanks for the tip. I didn't know, but I'll change it.  
SethMMorton Mainly ignorance, I suppose. I'm still working through the LPTHW tutorial and this is one of my first attempts at a practical application.  
asmeurer Great point. I redid it using namespaces (or whatever the equivalent to C namespaces is in Python: import numpy as np)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output of one of your sympy calculations is a sympy `Float` object which is not an object that numpy recognizes as something that should be coerced into a C `double`. Instead, it just makes an object array out of it (i.e. `dtype=object`). The way that numpy ufuncs work on object arrays is to look for methods of the same name on the objects, so `numpy.sqrt(solf10)` is doing what amounts to `numpy.array([x.sqrt() for x in solf10])`.

Explicitly coerce the values in your lists to true `float`s.

```
solf10 = [float(x) for sub1 in solf10 for x in sub1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you notice that your following code:

```
# Collected data
m10 = [1540,1500,1400,1400,1670]
m10kg = [x/1000 for x in m10]
...
```

You divide integers with integers, so resulting in a list with rounded numbers e.g. :

```
m10kg = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

You can repair it easily by dividing it with 1000.0 so it will be converted to float series, just like this:

```
# Collected data
m10 = [1540,1500,1400,1400,1670]
m10kg = [x/1000.0 for x in m10]
...
```

So in general in case of division:

```
float = float / float
int = int / int
float = int / float
float = float / int
```

Comment: Thank you for this! I don't have the reputation to upvote you, but it's really helpful.

Comment: @user2224491 You really should just be using arrays not lists here. Instead of `m10 = [1540,1500,1400,1400,1670]` `m10kg = [x/1000 for x in m10]`, use `m10 = np.array([1540,1500,1400,1400,1670])`
`m10kg = m10/1000.`

Comment: @askewchan Thanks. I've converted them to that. What's a good guideline for using arrays vs. lists? I'm figuring most linear algebra tasks should use arrays, but what are some other times I should use them?

Comment: I'd use them even for stuff that's not strictly linear algebra, but involves lots of numerical calculations.  Essentially, if you have code where you've imported numpy for some reason or other, use an array for any list that you have of uniform type that you plan to do a calculation with (you can't have a numpy array with some ints and some floats, e.g.).  If you're just storing numbers or plan to loop through them, a list is fine.  Even most loops can be done automatically and faster with numpy, like the example of dividing in my previous comment.